# Keep state of background slider on page reload/page swich

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help to get a background slider that i created to not reset from the beginning if i switch pages on a site just keep the state and keep sliding.

**My code:**

```
<script>
   jQuery(function()
   {
      var body = jQuery('body');
      var backgrounds = 
      [
         'url(bg1.jpg)',
         'url(bg2.jpg)',
         'url(bg3.jpg)', 
         'url(bg4.jpg)'
      ];
      var current = 0;

      function nextBackground()
      {
          body.css('background', backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

          setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
      }
      setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
      body.css('background', backgrounds[0]).fadeIn(3000);
   });
    console.log('testing');
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance for your sugestions!

Comment: You can use localstorage to persist the state, and later retrieve it from another page.

Comment: As far as using localStorage, the approach is twofold:
1. When the DOM loads, retrieve the currently saved background from your storage if it exists or use the first background if it doesn't
2. Every time you update a background, save it into the storage as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to store temporary data, such as current picture id and restore it back each page loading. If you want to use jQuery, you may directly connect [Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

```
$(function() {
    var body = $('body');
    var backgrounds = ['url(http://gallery.photo.net/photo/6154536-lg.jpg)',
    'url(http://gallery.photo.net/photo/8492321-md.jpg)', 'url(http://gallery.photo.net/photo/5674653-lg.jpg)', 
    'url(http://gallery.photo.net/photo/6597417-md.jpg)'];
    var current = $.cookie('backSlider') != null?$.cookie('backSlider') :0;;

    function nextBackground() {
        body.css('background', backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
        $.cookie('backSlider', current);
    }

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
    body.css('background', backgrounds[current]).fadeIn(3000);
});
console.log('testing');
```

**There can be collisions, if two pages with same code are loaded synchronously**

---

The other variant of solution for preventing collisions is to use server, which will be connected to each client via sockets (or setInterval ajax, but it can be less effective way), and it also will be responsible for switching backgrounds (the main advantage of using server is that it can serve everything in session, or, moreover, in database, to affect background changing for all the clients ever connected).